# Making CakePHP associations smarter

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I have three models associated with each other in my CakePHP application. I have an `Article` which belongs to both a `Category` and an `Author`. I query for an category’s latest articles like this:

```
$category = $this->Category->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.slug' => $slug
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Article' => array(
            'Author'
        )
    )
));
```

However, I’ve noticed this is *very* inefficient, as for every `Article` record it finds it queries my `authors` database table, even if I’ve already fetched that particular author’s details. So if I fetch 10 articles and they’re all by the same author, CakePHP will still issue 10 *separate* `SELECT` statements.

Can I make CakePHP “smarter” when using the Containable behavior so that it only issues the necessary queries? In my case, issue the first `SELECT` statement to find the author, and then use that result in subsequent `Article` rows if the ID matches.

Comment: Jep: Use Linkable Behavior or cusotm joins.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this through cake's api - the simplest would be to either set the Model's $recursive attribute to either -1 or 0, or use the Model's unbind() function